# Detect damage to device after dropping it?

Tags: screen, physical-damage, diagnostics

I dropped my Pixel. The screen is cracked and doesn't light up.
But the phone still works - it rings and vibrates when I get a call.

I'm considering replacing the screen myself, but before I buy the part, I'm wondering if there is any way to have confidence that the screen is the only problem.

Can I connect my phone to the computer via USB, and then run some kind of diagnostic software from the computer, to tell me exactly which parts are damaged besides the screen (if any)?

Comment: In China here, merchants that sell screen assembly online allows returning/refunding even if you tested the screen on your device, provided that it's still fit for selling again (e.g. you didn't already glue/screw it to your device, or peel off the protection film). You should ask the merchants you're looking to buy from and see if they have such policies. Having this means you can test if other parts of the device are broken with this screen, and even if yes you won't suffer significant financial loss.

Answer (score 0):

There is no diagnostic software AFAIK (as far as I know ). If there was, you would have heard of it

While things *seem* to be fine except for the screen , you can never be sure. The insides of phone are densely packed to maintain smaller thickness, size etc and it is quite possible that something else is also affected.

See sites like [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Google+Pixel+XL+Teardown/71237)  for help of you wish to do it on your own. You can never be *sure* that screen is the only damaged part

It's up to you but service centre may be an easier and better option, of course at higher cost and time (and missing out on the fun of doing it yourself :)

Comment: Diagnostic software may be available with OEMs but surely not in public domain. Just think of one manufacturer like Samsung and dozens of models be released by then and multiply that by the brands and you will see why it is not available